# Equivalence of ample divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety. Having ample anticanonical class is equivalent to having $-K_{X} > 0$? How to prove that? Does it hold for any ample divisor in $X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the equivalence holds for every ample divisor on $X$.
More precisely, if $X$ is a complex  compact Kähler manifold and if $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle on $X$ then we have the following celebrated equivalence due to Kodaira : $$L\; \text {is ample} \iff  L \; \text {is positive } $$     If such an $L$ exists, then $X$ is of course automatically a smooth  projective algebraic variety.

Let me remind you that:
1)  $L$ is said to be ample if there exists a positive  integer $m$ such that $M=L^{\otimes m}$ is very ample, which in turn means that there exists for some positive $N$  a closed embedding $i: X\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^N_\mathbb C$ such that $$M\cong i^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^N} (1))$$  2) $L$ is said to be positive if it can be endowed with a hermitian metric whose associated $(1,1)$ form $\omega$ is closed [meaning $d \omega=0$] and positive  [meaning $\omega(v,iv)\gt 0$ for all $x\in X$ and all nonzero tangent vectors $0\neq v\in T_x(X)$].

Your question is the special case where $L$ is the anti-canonical line bundle $L=\omega_X^{-1}=\mathcal O_X(-K_X)$.

Comment: Which books can I find that theorem and its proof?

Comment: You can consult Griffiths-Harris's *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* or Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I*.